# Proof for convexity of a fractional function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Any body knows how to prove convexity of this function?
$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\frac{1}{x_1-\frac{1}{x_2-\frac{1}{x_3}}}$$
for $$x_i>0$$

Update:
It seems this homework question is not right.
As @user854214 said in comments in some points the function is not defined.

Comment: This function is not always defined on the given domain. For example, what would be the value of $f(1, 1, 1)$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE, Ali! Please add motivation and your attempts till now, via editing your post (click in the lower left corner) so to avoid the future answerer will just feel doing your exercises.

Comment: You are right @user854214  Actually it was a question in my homework. So it seems the definition is not right. What if x_i>1?

Comment: sorry @user854214 edited previous comment.